# Silex and Doctrine2: Class not found with YML entities

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, composer-php, silex

I'm using Doctrine ORM with Silex via the [Doctrine ORM Service Provider](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider/) but I'm getting a MappingException with "class does not exist" each time I try to load data from the entity.

The exception:

```
MappingException in MappingException.php line 96: Class 'Project\Database\Mappings\Users' does not exist
```

File structure:

```
.
├───App
│   ├───Config
│   ├───Controllers
│   ├───Logs
│   └───Views
├───Doctrine
│   ├───Mappings
│   └───Repositories
```

I have my Entities in `Doctrine\Mappings`, defined as

```
Project\Database\Mappings\Users:
  type: entity
  repositoryClass: Project\Database\Repositories\UsersRepository
  table: users
  schema: transcribe
  id: [...]
  fields: [...]
```

I have the service registered like so (located in `App/init.php`):

```
// Register Doctrine ORM service
$app->register(new DoctrineOrmServiceProvider, [
    'orm.em.options' => [
        'mappings' => [
            [
                'type' => 'simple_yml',
                'namespace' => 'Project\Database\Mappings',
                'path' => __DIR__ . "/../Doctrine/Mappings",
            ]
        ]
    ],
]);
```

And in my sample controller (`App/Controllers/HomeController.php`),

```
class HomeController
{
    protected $twig;
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(Twig_Environment $twig, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
        $this->repo = $em->getRepository("Project\Database\Mappings\Users");
    }
}
```

My route for the sake of completion (`App/routes.php`):

```
use Project\App\Controllers\HomeController;

// Register controllers
$app['home.controller'] = function () use ($app) {
    return new HomeController($app['twig'], $app['orm.em']);
};

// Define routes
$app->get("/", "home.controller:index");
```

I do have the autoloader configuration set in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Project\\App\\": "App",
        "Project\\Database\\": "Doctrine"
    }
}
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the Doctrine or service provider documentation that stated I had to do anything special beyond that to make YAML entities work.

Comment: Do you have an actual user entity class? Your mapping file seem a bit off as well. http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/yaml-mapping.html

Comment: @JimL No, I do not have an actual class. I believe the YML mapping is supposed to take care of that for me.Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say my mapping file is off. I do have `id` and `fields`, but I intentionally left those out of the snippet and forgot to add in placeholders.

Comment: No the mapping file is only to map the class properties to whatever db layout you have. Doctrine supports generating the entity classes from the mappings though, depending on your setup you should be able to run some command to do that. The mapping file should refer to the entity it maps, ie User.dcm.yml should begin with `Project\Database\Mappings\User:`

Comment: The namespace issue that you pointed out was a copy/paste error. I've corrected it in my question. So, you're saying that entities are not the same thing as mappings, and that there is some way to generate it. I'm unfortunately having difficulty locating documentation for doing that using the dflydev service provider.

Comment: "dflydev" only provides a "connection" (service provider) to plug doctrine into Silex. You will need to extensively fall back to the [doctrine manual](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/), also note [how an annotated entity look](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider/issues/64). An annotated entity consists of both mappings and the class properties and methods. You have separated out the mappings into its own file (which I like to do in Doctrine), but you still need the entity class

Comment: @JimL Ah, I get how this works now. Can you format that as an answer so I can accept it for those looking for an answer in the future? Thanks for your help.